# General GUI for Script?

Tags: java, python, user-interface, command-line-interface, platypus

I wrote a Java program that takes a file as input on the command line.  The easiest way for me to call it with setting up all of the libraries correctly was to use ant, and I suggested that others do the same when running this script.

Apparently, there are people who are terrified of the command line (?!) and want to use a GUI to call this script.  As in, double click, and then navigate to the input file and click on it.

What do you suggest is the easiest way to do this, given that:

- users are presumably unable to use the command line
- there will be Mac users for sure, and potentially Windows users as well
- installation of the GUI needs to be absolutely painless

I looked into Platypus, but unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't appear to allow a user-chosen input.  I am leaning towards using Python GUI-building tools and pyexe to package, but I wanted to see if there are other tactics that may make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using Java, just use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).  Things to note:

- this is a Swing widget
- it'll work on both Mac and Windows, but may look a little different
- Swing can be a bit frustrating to work with (but so can any GUI toolkit, so this is a wash)
- doesn't require any painful installation -- just create a `.jar` file and distribute that

Here's the example given on that doc page:

JFileChooser provides a simple mechanism for the user to choose a file. For information about using JFileChooser, see How to Use File Choosers, a section in The Java Tutorial.

---

Here's the code example given on the linked docs page:

> The following code pops up a file chooser for the user's home
>   directory that sees only .jpg and .gif images:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you build an easy filechooser directly with Java?

Using netbeans you can really quickly assemble a Swing GUI.

(by the way I'd never want to use a console if avoidable)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html